# Ссылки в PDF

Tags: pdf, tcpdf, php, javascript, mpdf

Добрый день.

Столкнулись с такой проблемой.)) Есть PDF каталог товаров (текст и картинки), а в тексте цифровые коды товаров, вот, нужно как-то преобразовать эти коды в ссылки и отобразить документ в html. Суть в том, чтобы покупатель мог кликать на эти ссылки и сделать заказ.
Я думал преобразовать PDF на HTML а после уже с RegExp текст поменять на ссылки. А может, вариант из PDF->Word document, а потом уже показать на странице?

У кого-нибудь есть хорошие идеи?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в PDF документе сделать цифровые коды товаров букмарками (bookmarks), тогда они будут кликательными, даже если отображаются через плагин. На событие откликивания можно повесить JavaScript-овое событие перехода к оплате.

Comment: Спасибо, Михаил, но, если я не ошибаюсь, это невозможно, через Javascript взять клики из PDF объекта, может, есть примеры?

Comment: Описание javascript PDF API http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf